# Chrome.identity.getAuthToken returns invalid credentials?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, google-api-client

I have followed a few tutorials out there:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

https://github.com/GoogleDeveloperExperts/chrome-extension-google-apis

https://mashe.hawksey.info/2017/05/using-the-google-apps-script-execution-api-in-chrome-extensions/

to get my chrome extension to authenticate with a Google API project but this code:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': false }, function (token) {

    // Catch chrome error if user is not authorized.
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {

        $("#__sample_support_logarea").text(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        console.log('No token aquired');
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);

        sampleSupport.log('No token aquired');
        sampleSupport.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);


    } else {
        console.log('Token acquired');
        console.log(token);
    }

});
```

always returns:

```
OAuth2 request failed: Invalid credentials (credentials rejected by client).
```

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Shopify Partners",
  "description": "Automate Proposal Creation",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "main.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "identity",
    "https://accounts.google.com/*",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/*"
  ],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "..sr1t2ass4f9a0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ]
  },
  "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAp8Cj7TI9toe9nK0Pw8FFk1hOlSCPUwJ/GUmWUgzyO3XBP2KoIFv+ISpOoPO++itYsDaXBgZzjk/EUeFMPUWbmuL6+lfs6orq39mMzQKLZEMV05bRaVVsj7gMtBGrsuOJm83Ugw+2tUVszH/yCzMFYNGqJe+ZaEPyUDVqeOfbZoo+JDleDveu0j+HTKDa6wVdDxndT+N86IEoPKCWfXdzMZ6+22ZTSPKYIvQbaHalqEQ9YAc80eHaL0eQNq/+aEv3oNWm2rbB8fy79koQKkZBuWJqgWmznWe6NzPkEpsiE+ilaUCKzWzFDFpiIC0A5Eq3KpWQdnQYDF1A2gmTh9vgkQIDAQAB",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Please note that I have omitted the complete client id here for security reasons.

The only thing that I suspect might be the reason for this is that I am running an unpacked extension in chrome dev mode which id is something like: gcnonhfkghlloailceiddfmlmdeajlkl

And in the Api Console when creating the credentials for the client I have specified the same:

[image]

Therefore I suspect that being an unpackaged extension might be comprising it. But publishing an extension in the Chrome store is a long process and certainly is not what is expected of such a simple task.

Comment: The API needs a real extension in the web store because the web store creates a real sub-domain which is used to redirect the authentication, AFAIK.

Comment: I honest have no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your extension id has changed. The same thing happened to me.

[image]

To fix this, I again created google `OAuth 2.0 Client ID` and it has been fixed.